# How to make 3 dimensional array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a query string like

```
"1_timestamp=201612312&1_user=123&2_timestamp=20145333&2_user=5432";
```

But I want to make them in array like below.

```
array(
    0 => (
        timestamp = 201612312,
        user = 123,
        ),
    1 => (
        timestamp = 201612312,
        user = 123,
        ),
);
```

I'm sorry to show you php type of array though I'm new to java.

How do I make it something like that?

Thank you

Comment: Think of `Map`.

Comment: Write classes and create objects to represent your data instead of creating a multidiminesional array.

Comment: Do you want to *parse* the string `1_timestamp=201612312&1_user=123&2_timestamp=20145333&2_user=5432`?

Comment: @MCEmperor Parsing the string is not a big deal but arranging the string and put them into object is difficult for me

Comment: @EricLee You just caught the whole point of object-orientation. You have two related properties (timestamp and user), and they belong in a class (possibly named `Visit` or something?). You should just follow @apadana's format.

Comment: @MCEmperor Thank you for commenting. Now I feel like I got a tiny concept of Java's OOP. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest structure to what you are doing in php, and if your data has more fields it can be easily added to the Data class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Data {
    int timestamp;
    int user;

    Data(int ts, int user) {
        this.timestamp = ts;
        this.user = user;
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();
        Data d1 = new Data(201612312, 123);
        Data d2 = new Data(201612312, 123);
        data.add(d1);
        data.add(d2);

        System.out.println(data.get(1).user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is not the perfect one I was looking for though, This helped me got a point of figuring out how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without writing a class. You can use it like this.

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map1.put("1_timestamp", "201612312");
map1.put("1_user", "123");

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map2.put("2_timestamp", "20145333");
map2.put("2_user", "5432");

List<Map<String,String> mapList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
mapList.add(map1);
mapList.add(map2);

for (Map<String, String> map : list) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```